# Mailchimp for WP add subscriber programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

i am trying to add an user to a MailChimp list programmatically (so he is a subscriber of any emails i will send).
I do have the pro-version of the MailChimp for WordPress plugin.

Is there a way to add - and remove a user (Email and three fields) to a list dynamically?
There seems to be an API (http://developer.mc4wp.com/), but i did not found a function to do so.

Is there one?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`mc4wp_get_api`](http://developer.mc4wp.com/reference/functions/mc4wp_get_api/) function to grab an instance of the MailChimp for WordPress API. Then call the `subscribe()` function add an email to a list:

```
$list_id = "2341ca4321";
$email = "subscriber@email.com";
$api = mc4wp_get_api();
$api->subscribe($list_id, $email);
```

- The `subscribe()` function returns a boolean. This return value simply reports if the subscribe request succeeded. Will return `false` if the user is already on the list
- `$list_id` can be found when logged into MailChimp, looking under a list, `Settings > List name and campaign defaults > List ID`

Answer (score -1):

```
include('/MailChimp.php');
$MailChimp = new \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp("API-KEY");
$result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
$list_id = 'a0123a45f';  //  List Key
$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => test@test.com,
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields' => array('FNAME'=>'test', 'LNAME'=>'tester'),
            ]);
```